# Should the content inside title tags be trimmed?

Tags: html

The code that generates the content inside our title tags sometimes results in spaces between the tags and the content, like this:

```
<title>  The Page Title  </title>
```

Are there any known detrimental effects caused by this?

In our case, fixing this would lead to slightly less readable code. (It's not something where I can just trim the result.)

Comment: no, there are no detrimental affects for the extra spaces in this case. it just affects the cleanliness of the code.

Comment: Aside from further limiting the amount of characters that can be shown in a search engine, and the amount of characters that can be shown in the browser window's title, no.

Answer (score 0):

The spaces after the `<title>` tag and before the closing title tag make no difference. Unless you are adding `&nbsp;`

The dom does read the space between each letter/word.

The only thing i would say it affects is the readability of the HTML Markup.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any detrimental effects as far as I know.
You can try variations yourself like below and the title would still be **'The Title Page a'** (irrespective of browser)

```
<title>The Title          Page        a    </title>
```

However if you deliberately add a space using *nbsp;* then the spaces will show up in the title, which is hopefully not the problem with your code generator as per the question. 
For clean code purposes, it is better to fix code generator to avoid unwanted spaces.